# Linking other websites to my website for seo boost but they did not do the same business

Tags: seo, google-search, links, link-building

What affect does it make at page ranking if i link other websites to my website as my clients, like people i have worked for and i will place a link with their logo. Does it harm the ranking because every link will not be doing the same work that i do.

**Example.com (Doing web development work)**

- example1.com (Food Business)
- example2.com (Travel Agent)
- example3.com (Real Estate Company)

what if i link the above 3 links to **example.com**

Q1. Will example.com get boost in ranking.?

Q2. Will example.com get bad impresssion on google.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated or off-topic niche backlinks can damage your sites reputation unless they can be associated with one another through a brand or trading name.

For example:

- Stack Exchange

  - Stack Overflow
  - Pro Webmasters
- Dixons Retail

  - PC World
  - Currys
  - Knowhow
  - Dixons travel
  - DSGi Business

One or two off topic links isn't going to do a great deal in terms of being punished by Google or Bing but they are unlikely going to help either. You should only want to link in and from such websites if they are directly associated with one another because it helps promote the brand.

If ever in doubt... always use `rel="nofollow"` on your links.